# How to nest namspaced resources and avoid double namespacing - uninitialized constant ActsAs::ActsAs

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two namespaced models in a Rails app - ActsAs::Comments and ActsAs::Likes. Both are polymorphic, and belong to several different parent models. Improtantly for this question, Likes can belong to a Comment.

So my routes look something like this

```
namespace :acts_as do
  resources :comments do
    namespace :acts_as do
      resources :likes, only: :create
    end
  end
end 
resource :other_objects do
  namespace :acts_as do
    resources :likes, only: :create
  end
end
```

I then have a shared partial, called in the parent object's view, for adding likes.

```
<%= link_to 'Like', 
  polymorphic_path( 
    [ @object, ActsAs::Like.new ], 
    like: { likable_type: @object.class.name, likable_id: @object.id } 
  ) %>
```

This work's fine for OtherObjects, but not for Comments.

Rake routes shows

```
acts_as_comment_acts_as_likes  
POST     
/acts_as/comments/:comment_id/acts_as/likes(.:format)
acts_as/acts_as/likes#create
# note the double namespacing of the controller
```

Clicking 'like' gives

```
ActionController::RoutingError - uninitialized constant ActsAs::ActsAs:
```

What is the correct way to set this up and avoid this double namespacing of the controller?